# Solve $y'''+y^2y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

During my research work I found a non-linear differential equation $y'''+y^2y'=0$. Now I am stuck here. Please help me solve this.

Comment: Note that $y=0$ is a solution of the differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y' = 0$ it is easy to find the solution. Otherwise we have
\begin{align}
&y'''+y^2y'=0 \\
\int dx \implies& y''+\frac{y^3}{3}=C \\
\text{($y'$ is a nonzero function), }\ \cdot y' \implies &y'y''+\frac{y^3y'}{3}=Cy' \\
\int dx \implies & \frac{y'^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{12}=Cy + C'\\
\text{solve for }y'^2 \implies & y'^2 = -\frac{y^4}{6} + Cy +C'\\
\text{solve for }y' \implies & \frac{y'}{\sqrt{ -\frac{y^4}{6} + Cy + C'}} = \pm1 \\
\end{align}
and integrate...

Comment: Thanks sir, for your kind help.

Comment: You're Welcome!, I hope you can integrate it

Comment: Sure sir, now i can

Answer (score 1):

$$y'''+y^2y'=0$$
Note that $y=C$ is a solution of the differential equation. Integrate to reduce the order:
$$y''+\dfrac 13y^3=C$$
Multiply by $2y'$:
$$2y''y'+\dfrac 23 y^3y'=2Cy'$$
Integrate again.
$$y'^2+\dfrac 16 y^4=2C_1y+C_2$$
This is separable but not easy to integrate.
$$y'= \pm \sqrt  {K_1+K_2y-\dfrac 16 y^4}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir.

Comment: You're welcome @MANI